# Convert group of Txt files to excel workbook with each file as new sheet. Save excel file to new folder

Tags: excel, vba, csv, txt, file-conversion

Convert group of Txt files to excel workbook with each file as new sheet. Save excel file to new folder.
I am attempting to build a txt file conversion tool in excel. I am only able to convert one file at a time manually. Here is how I envision the process going
1.) Open CONVERSION TOOL (excel file)
2.) Select CONVERSION button which opens file explorer
3.) Select all files for conversion (Up to 50 .TXT files), the is a simple comma delimited conversion to columns
4.) Generates new excel file with converted data, one sheet per file
5.) Saves new excel file to designated folder
I have seen a few answers on here about how to do the conversion, I'm really more stuck on how to select multiple TXT files and convert into a new workbook

I have the following code which provides a similar function for a separate application. This program converts multiple file types into to excel with additional formatting. It allows multiple files to be selected at once and saves each converted file to a new workbook all placed in the same folder. I thought I could work off this to get started but I'm not familiar enough with VBA to know what to change.

```vb
Sub test()


    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim nFolder As String
    Dim nFileWithPath As String
    Dim nFile As String
    Dim extensionFileFile As String
    Dim nConvertedFile As String
    
    Dim folderIsOpen As Boolean
    folderIsOpen = False
    
    Dim message As String 'The user will see this message at the end of the conversion.
    message = ""
    
    Dim TestRunWith As String
    Dim waferDiameter As Integer 'this integer will allow the program to know if the tests comes from a 3-inches wafers or a 6-inches wafers.
    Dim targetVz As Integer 'this integer represent the target Vz. It can be 7V, 9V or 11V according to the test results.
    
    'Unprotect all useful sheets
    Sheets("Results-3-inch").Unprotect Password:="microchip"
    Sheets("Results-6-inch").Unprotect Password:="microchip"
    Sheets("Conversion").Unprotect Password:="microchip"
    Sheets("Conversion").Activate
        
    UserForm1.Show
    If (Sheets("Conversion").Range("TestRunWith").Value = Sheets("Conversion").Range("Tesectxt").Value) Then
        tester = "Tesectxt"
    Else
        If (Sheets("Conversion").Range("TestRunWith").Value = Sheets("Conversion").Range("TesecCsv").Value) Then
            tester = "TesecCsv"
        Else
            tester = "Fec"
        End If
    End If
  
  
    'Open the File Dialog to choose the files
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    fd.Title = "Select file(s)"
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True 'Allow the user to select more than one file
    
    If fd.Show() Then 'If the user opens a file
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Don't update the screen so that the user doesn't see the opening and closing windows
        
        For Each SelectedFile In fd.SelectedItems
            nFileWithPath = SelectedFile
            extensionFile = UCase(Right(nFileWithPath, Len(nFileWithPath) - InStrRev(nFileWithPath, ".")))
            
            If (extensionFile = "TXT" And tester = "Tesectxt") Or (extensionFile = "CSV" And tester = "TesecCsv") Or (extensionFile = "XLSX" And tester = "Fec") Then
                'If Len(Dir(nConvertedFile)) = 0 Then 'If the .xlsx file doesn't already exist
                
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells.ClearContents
                
                'File name :
                nFile = Right(nFileWithPath, Len(nFileWithPath) - InStrRev(nFileWithPath, "\"))
                nPath = Left(nFileWithPath, Len(nFileWithPath) - Len(nFile))
                nFile = Left(nFile, InStrRev(nFile, ".") - 1)
                
                'COPY DATA
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(nFileWithPath) 'Open the test file
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
                nFile = ws.Name
                Range("A1:L4000").Select 'Copy the data
                Selection.Copy
                    
                'PASTE DATA
                ThisWorkbook.Activate
                Sheets("Data").Activate
                Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Paste the data in the "Data" sheet
                Cells(1, 16).Value = nFile
                    
                'The Sheets Result will be updated with the new data.
                If (Sheets("DataConverted").Range("QtTests").Value < 400) Then 'if the number of tests is less than 400"
                    waferDiameter = 3 'the data comes from a 3-inch wafer.
                Else
                    waferDiameter = 6
                End If
                
                targetVz = Sheets("DataConverted").Range("TargetVz").Value
                
                If (UCase(Left(nFile, 2)) = "F9") Or UCase((Left(nFile, 2)) = "F8") Then
                    nFolder = nPath & Left(nFile, 5) & "-" & targetVz & "V-" & waferDiameter & "inches\"
                Else
                    If (UCase(Left(nFile, 2)) = "F1") Then
                        nFolder = nPath & Left(nFile, 6) & "-" & targetVz & "V-" & waferDiameter & "inches\"
                    Else
                    nFolder = nPath & nFile & "-" & targetVz & "V-" & waferDiameter & "inches\"
                    End If
                End If
                
                If Len(Dir(nFolder & nFile & ".xlsx")) = 0 Then 'if the file doesn't already exist
                    If Len(Dir(nFolder, vbDirectory)) = O Then 'if the folder doesn't already exist
                        MkDir (nFolder) 'create the new folder
                    End If
                    
                    'COPY RESULTS
                    If waferDiameter = 3 Then
                        Sheets("Results-3-inch").Copy
                    Else
                        Sheets("Results-6-inch").Copy
                    End If
                    
                    'PASTE RESULTS
                    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                        .Copy
                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    End With 'Paste values and format in a new Workbook
                
                    'SAVE RESULTS
                    wb.Close
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nFolder & nFile & ".xlsx"     'Save the new Workbook with the .csv file's name (.xlsx extension) in the created Folder
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear the clipboard so that no clipboard message appears on the user's screen
                    
                    Set objOFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    If (Len(Dir(nFolder & nFile & "-original." & extensionFile)) = 0) Then
                        objOFS.moveFile nFileWithPath, nFolder & nFile & "-original." & extensionFile
                    End If

                    message = message & "- Conversion of " & nFile & " (" & targetVz & "V, " & waferDiameter & " inches)." & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
                    
                Else
                    message = message & "-" & nFolder & nFile & ".xlsx" & " already exists." & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear the clipboard so that no clipboard message appears on the user's screen
                    wb.Close
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "ERROR: The file" & SelectedFile & " is incompatible with the tester " & tester
        End If
        Next SelectedFile
        
        If message = "" Then
            MsgBox "No file has been converted. Close this Message Box to continue.", , "End of Conversion"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'OPEN THE FOLDER WITH THE CONVERTED FILE
        nFolder = Left(nFileWithPath, InStrRev(nFileWithPath, "\") - 1)
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
            If Wnd.Name = "File Explorer" Then
            ' The folder may have not exactly the same path ("P:\Folder" and "\\max\public\Folder" for example).
            ' We compare the last part of both path to see if our folder isn't already open.
                lenSecondPartPath = IIf(Len(Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path) < Len(nFolder), Len(Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path) / 2, Len(nFolder) / 2)
                If Right(Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path, lenSecondPartPath) = Right(nFolder, lenSecondPartPath) Then folderIsOpen = True
            End If
        Next Wnd
        If folderIsOpen = False Then
            Shell Environ("WINDIR") & "\explorer.exe " & nFolder, vbNormalNoFocus
        End If
        
        Sheets("Conversion").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Update the screen
        
        message = message & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Close this Message Box to continue."
        MsgBox message, , "End of Conversion"
        
    End If
    Set fd = Nothing
    
    'Protect the Sheets.
    Sheets("Results-3-inch").Protect Password:="microchip"
    Sheets("Results-6-inch").Protect Password:="microchip"
    Sheets("Conversion").Protect Password:="microchip"
End Sub


Function CheckFileIsOpen(chkSumfile As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    
    CheckFileIsOpen = (Workbooks(chkSumfile).Name = chkSumfile)
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Function
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\")

' set the starting point to write the data to
'Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Write file-name
    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveCell = file.Name

    ' open the file
    Set txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file)

    col = 2
    Do While Not txtFile.AtEndOfStream
        dat = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Split(txtFile.ReadLine, ","), 1, 0))
        sh.Cells(LastRow, col).Resize(UBound(dat), 1) = dat
        col = col + 1
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    txtFile.Close
    'Range(cl.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```